# Connecting to a Remote EJB Module running in Docker

Tags: java, jboss, docker, ejb

To deploy and run an application client that connects to an EJB module on a Enterprise Server instance that is running in a Docker container, one must expose the ports that are used to establish the remote call.

- Which are those ports?
- Are they fixed or vary between calls?
- Do I need to configure anything else in Docker?

I'm using Jboss 5.1.0 as Enterprise Server and I've tried exposing ports 1099 and 1100, getting in both cases exceptions. Same test using a Jboss running in my host works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The following are the required ports to connect to an EJB module running in a JBoss 5 Server:

  *1099* : Naming service port.

  *1098* : RMI service port.

  *3873* : EJB3 Remote Invoker Port.
- Those ports are fixed. Do not vary between calls
- In Docker, you just need to redirect those ports.

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 1099:1099 -p 1098:1098 -p 3873:3873 -d jboss-image`

Comment: If using eap 6.4, the ports are explained here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Socket_Binding_Groups.html#Network_Ports_Used_By_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_62. I exposed 8080 9990 4447 9999 and was able to connect to remote EJBs after adding an application user (necessary for remote servers... ```/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/add-user.sh -a --user <user> --password <password> --silent``` as per ```remote.connection.default.username``` and ```remote.connection.default.password```)